# If A = diag(1, 3) and B = diag(3, 1) show that A and B are similar (find an M).

Tags: matrices

Please show me steps how you would solve it. I'm really lost and detailed explanation would help me learn and understand it better.

Comment: Please don't put the full question in your title, put it in the body of your post. Also, give a detailed explanation of what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\0 & 3\end{array}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{array}{cc}3 & 0\\0 & 1\end{array}\right)$, find an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix $M$ such that $MAM^{-1}=B$. Hint: Use an $M$ whose entries are only $1$'s and $0$'s.